# Are quasicomponents connected in a compact non-Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology

Are quasicomponents connected in a compact space?

Background:

- [Quasicomponents are connected in a compact Hausdorff space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600904/51161).
- [A non-compact locally compact Hausdorff space may not have connected quasicomponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1884546/51161).
- It can be shown that a subset is an open connected component if and only if it is an open quasicomponent. (*)
- In a finitely generated space (aka Alexandrov discrete space), every intersection of open subsets is open. Hence every quasicomponent is open as an intersection of clopen subsets. By (*), the quasicomponents are connected.
- More generally, a space with open components (a sumconnected space) has connected quasicomponents by (*). This includes locally connected spaces, which include finitely generated spaces.

So this question is about whether the first result can be generalized to non-Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: @Ulli It's correct. I'll accept if you write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following counter-example is taken from [A. Tarizadeh, Idempotents and connected components, Example 3.15](https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.05185)
(but I'm pretty sure that it appeared elsewhere long before):

Define $Y = \{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R$ and
define $X = Y \cup \{0^*\}$ by doubling $0$, i.e. X is the subspace of the [line with two origins](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000083/).

Obviously, $Y$ is compact, $T_1$.
Moreover, every clopen set, which contains $0$, also contains $0^*$.
As each $\{\frac{1}{n}: n \ge m\} \cup \{0, 0^* \}$ is clopen, the quasi-component of $0$ is $\{0, 0^* \}$.
However, $\{0, 0^* \}$ is discrete, hence not connected.